# Joomla to wordpress migration - How to migrate fb comments?

Tags: facebook, wordpress, migration, joomla1.5

I am migrating one of my sites to new cms and I would like to know if there's a way to migrate facebook comments too together with content, users, templates and etc? 
In old joomla site I was using: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/social-comments/16890 this plugin for comments, if that makes the difference :)

I am using joomla 1.5 and WordPress 3.4.1 versions. Any posible solutions are wellcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot import Facebook comments, because Facebook needs to associate each comment with a Facebook user. They don't allow importing because they couldn't verify that the user actually made all the comments you may be saying they made, which would be a big potential area for spam or misuse.